# Document picker in Swift

Tags: swift4, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I'm trying to open document picker view controller on a click of a button, but there are no option shown in it. Only more option is shown as u can see in the screen shot. I want to show options of iCloud, google drive, dropbox etc. I just want to get any document, image or pdf file from the cloud storages and want to show it in my application. I have tried this code,

```
 @available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {


    let cico = url as URL
    print("The Url is : \(cico)")


    //optional, case PDF -> render
    //displayPDFweb.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: cico) as URLRequest)




}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func documentMenu(_ documentMenu:     UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {

    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {

    print("we cancelled")

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


}
@IBAction func docsBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It is only this in picker controller,
[image]

But i want to show option in this controller and when click it should take us to that cloud storage. I have also enable the iCloud option from capabilites of my application.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? I'm seeing the same behavior, but haven't been able to find any answers related to this issue.

Comment: yup i have done the scenario. @brandogs